# Delphi printing Unicode with TextOut

Tags: delphi, unicode

Using `Canvas.TextOut()` or something similar, is there a way to print a checkmark or Unicode character? Does a particular font have to be installed for it to work?

Comment: Yes, you can use a Unicode character for a checkmark, such as U+2713. Of course, you need to have a font selected into the Canvas that supports rendering that character.

Comment: The Segoe MDL Assets font has many useful characters for this

Comment: Thank you. Could you show me please an example of code? I can't seem to find a representation of var MyString: String; MyString:= //unicode 2713... Thanks

Comment: An example using it as a character literal using a numeric hex value in Delphi would be: `#$2713` so `MyString := #$2713;`

Comment: Also see; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146533/delphi-draw-a-unicode-character